# matlab image frequency domain filtering

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, frequency

For example, I have an arbitrary filter:

```
H = 12*(sin(PI*u)*cos(PI*v))
```

How can I apply this filter to an image? What I searched on the internet about applying filters, it is like using matlab inner filter models, which is not like this one.

I am new to image processing, thank you for your help.

Comment: you want do it in frequency domain or time domain ?

Answer (score 3):

Filtering in frequency domain:

```
originalImage_fft = fft2(originalImage);
filter_fft = fft2(filter);

resultImage_fft = originalImage_fft .* filter_fft;
resultImage = ifft2(resultImage_fft);
```

Filtering in time domain:

```
resultImage = conv2(originalImage, filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageFreDomain = fft2(ImageTimeDomain);
FilteredImageFreDomain = ImageFreDomain .* H;
FilteredImageTimeDomain = real(ifft(FilteredImageFreDomain));
imagesc(FilteredImageTimeDomain)
```

I would suggest you use `sin(pi*a*u)*cos(pi*b*v)`, you may need to tune the value of `a` and `b` to best filter out your high frequency noise in the image while still keep those edge features.

Comment: Thank you. So for the sin can vectorized multiply cos, does it mean, their rows and columns should be like X*Y and Y*Z, and X, Z are the number of rows and columns of the image?

Comment: Yes. And I also suggest you use H=exp(-(u.^2+v.^2)/a) for a comparison of the two low-pass filters

Answer (score 0):

Applying a filter in frequency domain means applying the [Fourier Transform of Convolution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Convolution_theorem) 
This is as simple as multiplying Filter and Signal.

```
filteredImage = H.*Image
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the filter of Image Processing Toolbox [imfilter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) for this purpose. The syntax for your application would be:

```
FilterImage = imfilter(Image, H)
```